# Using OpenGL in Visual Studio 2010 - error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I am compiling this OpenGL program in Visual Studio. I have set it up properly, after reading numerous articles. I have added the correct libraries to linker's additional dependencies. However I am getting this error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *WinMain@16 referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup

The code I am compiling is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void init(void) 
{
   glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);
}

void display(void)
{
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   glLoadIdentity ();             /* clear the matrix */
           /* viewing transformation  */
   gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glScalef (1.0, 2.0, 1.0);      /* modeling transformation */ 
   glutWireCube (1.0);
   glFlush ();
}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{
   glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h); 
   glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity ();
   glFrustum (-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0);
   glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize (500, 500); 
   glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
   init ();
   glutDisplayFunc(display); 
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
   glutMainLoop();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two kind of executables in Windows:

1. Console
2. GUI (Windows)

Only difference is that Console executables automatically opens console window, and C/C++ CRT runtime associates standart stdout/stdin/stderr handles to go to this window. Otherwise there are no differences between these two executable types - both can create new Windows, draw things, use OpenGL, etc...

In visual Studio, if you create Console application - then it expects your entry point to be called "main". But for GUI application it expects entry point function to be called "WinMain". So you have two options if you don't want to see Console window when your application starts:

1. Change project linker settings to indicate you are building GUI application (Project Properties -> Linker -> System -> Subystem = Windows). This will require your entry point function to be called WinMain: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381406.aspx
2. Indicate to linker that even if you want to use GUI application, but you want your entry point to be called "main". You can do that in Project Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point = mainCRTStartup. Don't put there main. Put there mainCRTStartup - it is special C/C++ CRT function that initializes standard C library and calls your main function automatically. Heres the documentation about this setting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx

Using second options means, that you can use GLUT, have your entry point called "main" and have no Console window opened at startup.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using some non-standard Microsoft extension that doesn't expect you to define `main`, but `WinMain`.

Try defining main as:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

or

```
int WinMain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I get this error: expected '(' to follow 'argv'; syntax error: ')'

Comment: That won't work, either you should define `WinMain` with its correct arguments or make the whole application into a console application (which is what GLUT expects anyway). This way the linker error will still be there since `WinMain@16` which is what the linker expects requires 16 bytes worth of parameters and you're only supplying 8 bytes...(besides that the fact that `__tmainCRTStartup` invokes `WinMain` with a completely different set of parameters).

Comment: @user1279782 try char instead of TCHAR then, it's probably because you don't have unicode defined.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: This solution is broken. If you use GLUT you should create a console app since GLUT will create the render window for you. If you don't want a console app, then don't use GLUT and create your own OpenGL rendering window, but in that case the prototype for `WinMain`should be the correct one: `int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)`.

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson creating a console application still requires _tmain instead of main. Try it out.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: changed it to console.. got it to work, GLUT opens up a new window. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: No, MSVC supports two variants of `main()`, `main()` and `wmain()`. The first for ASCII/Multi-byte support and the other for UTF-16/wide-char support. The `_tmain()` you are referring to is a define that will resolve to either `main` or `wmain` depending on whether your application is built as unicode or not.

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson yes, so it has nothing to do with console/windows application.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Well, `main()` & `wmain()` are the application entry points for console applications (depending on ASCII or Unicode), the corresponding entry points for windows applications are `WinMain()` & `wWinMain()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your project as a console application instead of a Windows application.

If you *do not* want your program to be a console app you need to skip using GLUT. What you do then is create a normal Windows application and create your own OpenGL rendering window. It's quite an involved process but [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) has tutorials for all your OpenGL-programming needs. In this case I would recommend [this](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_%28win32%29/13001/) one.

Comment: one question.. will i still be able to use all the drawing functionalities, having made this a console application? Thanks!

Comment: GLUT will open a window for you in which all OpenGL drawing will take place.

Comment: So what does he use the console window for?  This is not the proper solution.  Albeit that this wouldn't be the first program I've seen that briefly flashes up a console window.

Comment: This *is* the proper solution when using GLUT in Windows. If you do not want the console window, you need to skip GLUT and create your own OpenGL rendering window (you can google for how to do that, it's a bit involved). And unless you explicitly kill the console window, it will remain there for the runtime of the program.

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson What you are saying is not true. You can use GLUT without opening console window and still have entry point called main. Read my answer how to do that.

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko: Calling me a liar because I recommend the proper supported way of doing things is quite an overreaction. Of course you can do it your way, but ASFAIK Microsoft could make changes so that the /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS+/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup-combo is no longer supported.

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson I'm not calling you liar. I'm just saying it is not true - that you can not use GLUT (without console window) and not create window yourself (if you don't want to see console window). Solution with manually setting subsystem+entry is completely valid solution. It is documented by Microsoft themselves and is used already for a very long time (since Visual C++ 6 if I'm not mistaken). I doubt it that they want to break a ton of software out there.