# setup visual studio to windows subsystem with openGL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, opengl, glfw

How do I setup my project so that it opens a window instead of console?

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\glfw.h>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwOpenWindow(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

This code opens a window but it also opens a console, how do setup my project so that only window appear?
Using VS 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker automatically assumes you want to use the console subsystem when you have a function named `main`. A few obvious (but untested) possibilities would be:

1. Use an entry-point named WinMain
2. Explicitly specify `-subsystem:windows` to the linker
3. (1|2) use a completely different entry point, tell the linker both the entry point and the subsystem.

Comment: Thanks, the WinMain option works. but When I setup the entry point to something else for example "Test" and rename the main() into Test() I got this error: Error **error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup** Can you please explain how to setup that? :)

Comment: You have to tell it the entry point you want to use with `-entry:Test`. I kind of put those in order though -- if using `WinMain` works, that's almost certainly the easiest, most dependable way to go.

Comment: **Poject properties > linker > advanced > entry point > ...** What to type into that field? none of them work Test or -entry:Test, even when seting up in command line option :( for example **Poject properties > linker > advanced > command line > ...** -entry:Test

Comment: Here is info about how to keep your entry point named "main" and create window-type executable instead of console-type: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10156605/675078

Comment: Thank you alot for that link Martinš

Comment: sometimes the console output is not so bad - especially for the debug purpose, you can simply put printf messages and quickly see what is going on with your program.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6882500/524368

(Verbatim quote):

---

In the project build linker options set

```
/SUBSYSTEM:windows
/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup
```

Or use the following *#pragma* in the source file with the `int main(...)`

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

instead of

```
int main()
```

and set SubSystem to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) in Project properties/Linker/System

Don't forget to add

```
#include "Windows.h"
```